# Using piped output from find in uglify-js and sass

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I'm exploring the usage of NPM as a build tool and have run into an issue that's got me stumped. What I'd like to do is use find to get a list of files and then pipe these into a command like uglify-js or sass:

```
find ./views -type f -name '*.js' | uglifyjs xargs -o public/js/script.min.js
```

In both uglify-js and sass I get a version of this error:

> ERROR: can't read file: xargs

I'm not entirely sure if what I'm attempting to do is even possible, or if I should be going about it in a different way. I know I can achieve what I'd like with:

```
uglifyjs views/*.js views/**/*.js -o public/js/script.min.js
```

I can see that becoming a bit unwieldy in larger projects if your .js files are scattered across multiple directories, hence my interest in using something like find to get a list of files.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `find` + `xargs` combination in a wrong way. It should have been

```
find ./views -type f -name '*.js' | xargs -I{} uglifyjs "{}" -o public/js/script.min.js
```

With the `-I{}` flag in `xargs`, the `"{}"` becomes a placeholder for the output file name returned from the `find` command,

If your `find` version supports the `-print0` option (It is usually part of `GNU findutils` and does not occur in `FreeBSD` version of the command.), which is more efficient way to handle files having spaces or special characters in their names by embedding a `\0` character at end of each file. Now with an option in `xargs` with `-0` reads input from `stdout` with that character as delimiter.

```
find ./views -type f -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} uglifyjs "{}" -o public/js/script.min.js
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The only issue is it doesn't work with uglifyjs as it only minifies the last filename returned from find. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: @mike: Appreciate it, but hope the logic to use `find` output with `xargs` is clear now?